# Practical implementations of Multiparty computations

Tags: multiparty-computation

Are there any practical implementations and or software platforms to prototype applications based on MPC ?

Comment: Example: http://www.dyadicsec.com/

Comment: See also [Real world use cases of Multi-Party Computation](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/5192/33885).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is the [Might Be Evil framework](http://mightbeevil.com/framework/download.html) and [FairplayMP](http://www.cs.huji.ac.il/project/Fairplay/). The [hcrypt project](http://www.hcrypt.com/) also has a secure function evaluation library.

**UPDATE:**

Also, [VIFF](http://viff.dk/) and [SCAPI](http://crypto.biu.ac.il/about-scapi) (though as of writing this, the SCAPI framework is not fully released).

**March 2016:**

I just came across [FRESCO](https://fresco.readthedocs.org/).

Answer (score 2):

1. SEPIA http://www.sepia.ee.ethz.ch/
2. FairPlay, FairPlayMP http://www.cs.huji.ac.il/project/Fairplay/
3. FastGC
   https://github.com/yhuang912/FastGC
4. FlexSC
   https://github.com/wangxiao1254/FlexSC
5. SecureC from ShareMind
   (request them for software based on your needs) 
   VIFF http://viff.dk/