# Freely available softwares for simulating/implementing MPC protocols

Tags: reference-request, implementation, multiparty-computation, protocol-analysis, resources

I have been designing multiparty computation (MPC) protocols for functions that interest me. Although theoretically I am able to deduce the asymptotic complexity of the protocol, I wish to know as to how this protocol will perform for practical sized inputs. I came across VIFF (virtual ideal functionality framework) written in python which allows us to implement/simulate MPC protocols. However, with just basic knowledge of MPC I am finding it difficult to write programs in VIFF. My question is as follows:

Is there some nice resource/tutorial available online in regard to VIFF? If not VIFF, can you point me to any other freely available software which can be used for simulationg/implementing MPC protocols that has nice tutorials for beginners.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Practical implementations of Multiparty computations](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3400/practical-implementations-of-multiparty-computations)

Comment: Is there a nice tutorial for beginners for any of these MPC implementation softwares?

Comment: SEPIA has tutorial and ShareMind have nice documentation , did not check for others , but end of the day its java/c/python code big deal ?

Comment: SCAPI https://github.com/cryptobiu/scapi.

Comment: You might be interested in the open-source [Sharemind SDK](https://sharemind-sdk.github.io/) which includes an emulator to test and predict the running time of your MPC program.